# How to evaluate replacement part in re.sub?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string say 'Alex 28'. Now, I want to extract the number 28 and add it by 2 using regex.

In Perl, I could have got it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str='Alex 28';
$str=~s/(\d+)/$1+2/e;
```

To achieve this in Python, I tried the below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

str = 'Alex 28'

match=re.sub(r'(\d+)',r'\g<1>',str)
```

How do I add 2 to the '`\g<1>`' which has been fetched? I tried using int function, it is not working. Please help.

Version: Python 2.7.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` by [supplying a function to the `repl` argument](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

> If repl is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of pattern. The function takes a single match object argument, and returns the replacement string.

For example:

```
def add_two(match):
    return str(int(match.group()) + 2)

s = 'Alex 28'
re.sub(r'(\d+)', add_two, s)
```

Or, using a lambda:

```
re.sub(r'(\d+)', lambda m: str(int(m.group()) + 2), s)
```

Please note that:

- Using `str` as a variable name is a bad choice as it overrides the builtin `str`
- Substitution works with strings exclusively, so the function passed as `repl` argument should return a string
- I used `match.group()` which returns the whole match: you may need the specify the group index if the regex defines multiple groups.

Comment: So, whenever one wants to do some evaluation on the pattern matched, it always can be done only through a user-defined function or a lambda function, not directly as in perl?

Comment: I think so yes: regex in Python are a library, not a part of the language (as I believe they are in Perl).

Comment: what if there is two different match groups?